# How does jconsole get all the information he needs?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I want to make a system to gather some data of the JVM and notify me at certain levels, jconsole have this data, but I have no idea how it collects such data.
Does someone know a way to gather this data programatically with java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [the docs for JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), it "is a monitoring tool that complies to the Java Management Extensions (JMX) specification" and "uses the extensive instrumentation of the Java Virtual Machine" to gather datta.

In other words, it uses [the Java Management Extensions (JMX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions).

JMX provides a *ton* of data from various sources within the JVM, and new data sources can be defined by libraries. These are advertised using [managed beans (JMX MBeans)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/), which use a particular set of defs or annotations to indicate that they provide data or operations, what, and how.

with the JMX 2.0 spec, you can [use a set of annotations](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072243/playing-with-jmx-2-0-annotations.html) to mark your beans, making it fairly easy to provide data. Depending on your container, adding new beans [may be trivial](http://blog.kamranzafar.org/index.php/2009/04/24/guice-and-jmx-on-jboss/). JMX can act as both a data source and allow methods to be called from the console or other client, actually allowing you to perform (supported) operations on the VM being watched.

Various containers (such as [Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring)) and libraries (such as [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management)) provide additional metrics, in addition to [the slew of beans the JVM provides](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html). These expose such things as [memory usage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) (one of the more popular).

These beans are exposed by the JVM over [a pair of ports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) using a `domain: key-property-list` [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/best-practices-jsp-136021.html#mozTocId434075). Each bean and property exposes some relevant information, which clients like JConsole can use to build the tree of available beans and each screen with counters and buttons.

Comment: Is there a book that show those kinds of advanced concepts?